# Access screen height and width in a service worker

Tags: service-worker

I want my service worker to get the height and width of the screen.

I've tried screen.height, self.innerHeight, window.innerHeight, but it seems service workers run on a different context where these are undefined.

Is there a way to access device information like height and width within the context of a service worker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Service Workers (and all workers in general) can't access the DOM.

I can see two ways to achieve what you want:

1. Store those values in IndexedDB (or in a Cache) in your page and access them in the worker;
2. Send those values from the page to the service worker using `postMessage`.

Obviously, you can use the first solution always, you can't use the second solution when your service worker is running and there isn't any page open.

Comment: Can i write to a cache from my main page and then read the same from serviceworker .I am aware of indexDB solution but i want to know if there any other way to share common memory between SW and my application ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Cache API in your main page. `caches` is defined both in `window` and in the service worker global scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/caches - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/caches

Comment: but it says it is a read-only property so will i be able  add the height and width in the cache , and how can i access the same cache from both serviceworker and main page , with the same name?    Can i do something like this cache.put("height", window.innerHegiht)  from my main page ?

Comment: Yes, caches are shared, so you can access the same cache by using the same name.

Comment: i tried cache.put('height', innerHeight); , but it says parameter 2 is not type of 'Response' , what is the correct format for adding value in cache ?

Comment: @user17981 you might want to create a new question, since this is a little out of topic here. Anyway, the correct format is what the error message tells you, it should be a `Response` object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).